# Files are moved to Completed folder even though the processor throws an exception

Tags: apache-camel

I have a weird issue in the below code. Grabbed file from file path and send it to downstream system using the below code. But the issue is when Actual processor class throws an exception , the file is getting moved from inprogress folder and then completed folder. But it should not happen like this. What I want is that file should be remain in same file location (InProgress), until the processor process the file successfully. What am i doing wrong here?
'''

```
from("file:src/path?preMove=InProcess&move=Completed&delete=false&idempotent=false&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}&readLock=rename&readLockMinAge=10s&renameUsingCopy=true&filterFile=$simple{file:size} > 0 &include=.*.xml")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .routeId("test-route")
                .doTry().bean(ActualProcessor.class, "process")
                .doCatch(Throwable.class)
                .to("file:src/path?move=Reprocess")
                .end();
'''
```

Comment: By using `doTry()..doCatch()` you've basically handled the exception which causes the exchange to complete successfully. Same thing would apply if you would use `.onException(Exception.class).handled(true).end()`.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman, Thanks for your comments. My use case is .. just in case if any issue comes then move file to /Reprocess folder and if success move to /Inprogress and then /Completed folder. But this is not happening with the doTry and doCatch blocks

Comment: Like I said, since you've caught and handled the exception so file-component assumes that processing the file was successful and that you've solved any problems that where found in your try..catch block. Don't know if there's way to signal the file-component someway that the processing the file has failed other than to let the exception fall through. For this you could just remove try..catch block and use `moveFailed`